# In Gradle, how can I determine what dependency is accessing an external Maven repo?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I implemented an internal Nexus server to cache our build artifacts. In one of my Java modules, I removed all the references to external repos and replaced them with our internal repo in its `build.gradle` file. However I still see lines like this when I do a build.

```
Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant-antlr/1.9.4/ant-antlr-1.9.4.jar
```

Obviously the module has dependencies that download artifacts from the external repo. How can I determine which dependencies still has `build.gradle` settings that still use extenal repos? Thanks!